# bootstrap second tab content starts after leaving space for first tab content div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Simple Bootstrap 3 Tabs:

https://jsbin.com/yakuja/edit?html,output

I am creating tabs using bootstrap 3. Only issues is that the contents of second tab starts after adding the space on top for first tab.

In ideal scenario there should be no space above content

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href="#uploadFormat" data-toggle="tab">Client Upload Format</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#upload" data-toggle="tab">Client Bulk Upload</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <br/>
        <div class="tab pane fade active in" id="uploadFormat">
            <div class="form-bottom">
                <p>saurabh</p>
                <p>saurabh</p>
                <p>saurabh</p>
                <p>saurabh</p>
                <p>saurabh</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab pane fade" id="upload">         
            <form>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="client_upload_file">Upload Client File</label>
                    <input type="file" name="client_upload_file" id="client_upload_file"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="clientUpload">Upload Client File</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *syntax error* in class name at line:

```
<div class="tab pane fade" id="upload">
//             ^
```

To solve problem it should be:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="upload">
```

***[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/LLbs3mn4/)***

Answer (score 0):

If you have this same issue, but no typos causing it, try changing your CSS `tab-content` attribute from "`display: none`" to "`visibility: hidden`"

```
.tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display: block; /* undo "display: none;" */
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

That fixed this issue for me.